# I'm having trouble with the OR operator in my python code

Tags: python, logical-operators

I'm trying to make a search system which has multiple ANDs and ORs and brackets. While I'm making the code, I'm having some trouble with the OR. I don't know if my code is wrong or if my computer is wrong, because sometimes it gives the right answer and sometimes it doesn't.

```py
sentence = ["A", "B", "C"]
bracket = ["X", "or", "B"]

if "or" in bracket:
   index_of_or = bracket.index("or")
   if bracket[index_of_or -1 ] or bracket[index_of_or +1] in sentence:
      bracket = "True"
      print(bracket)
   else:
      bracket = "False"
      print(bracket)
```

I was checking the code by changing the elements in the bracket list.
I put `bracket=['X', 'or', 'Z']`
and the output was True.

Why is this happening?

Comment: This is a dupe, but I can't find it. Anyway, you're reading it like an English sentence. You need `if bracket[index_of_or-1] in sentence or bracket[index_of_or+1] in sentence`.

Comment: just add parentheses `(bracket[index_of_or -1 ] or bracket[index_of_or +1])`

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the conditional statement. You can't do something like 
`if x or y == 7 : ...`, you have to do `if x == 7 or y == 7`.

With that in mind, change the corresponding line of your code to read

```py
if bracket[index_of_or -1 ] in sentence or bracket[index_of_or + 1] in sentence:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = ["A", "B", "C"]
bracket = ["X", "or", "Z"]

if "or" in bracket:
   index_of_or = bracket.index("or")
   if (bracket[index_of_or -1 ] or bracket[index_of_or +1]) in sentence:
      bracket = "True"
      print(bracket)
   else:
      bracket = "False"
      print(bracket)
```

**Output**

`False`

Answer (score 0):

The problem's occurring because of this statement:

```
if bracket[index_of_or -1 ] or bracket[index_of_or +1] in sentence:
```

This actually does something very different than it appears. It evaluates to true if either:

- `bracket[index_of_or -1 ]` evaluates to true, or
- `bracket[index_of_or +1] in sentence` evaluates to true.

but you're thinking that it evaluates to true if either:

- `bracket[index_of_or -1 ] in sentence` evaluates to true, or
- `bracket[index_of_or +1] in sentence` evaluates to true.

The first conditional (`bracket[index_of_or -1 ]`) will be evaluated to `True` if the number is not 0. This is evaluating to `False` because `index_of_or = bracket.index("or")` returns 1, and `bracket[index_of_or -1 ]` makes it 0, thus making it evaluate to `False`.

To fix it, just change your program to this:

```
sentence = ["A", "B", "C"]
bracket = ["X", "or", "B"]

if "or" in bracket:
   index_of_or = bracket.index("or")
   if (bracket[index_of_or -1 ] or bracket[index_of_or +1]) in sentence:
      bracket = "True"
      print(bracket)
   else:
      bracket = "False"
      print(bracket)
```

and the output will be `False`, as intended.

Comment: Huh, I've never seen the `("a" or "b") in "other_string"` before. That's a really neat trick.

Comment: Agreed, @Modelmat. I was so happy when I learned I didn't have to write `if w in somelist or x in somelist or y in somelist or z in somelist`. All that's needed is a simple `if (w or x or y or z) in somelist` :)

Comment: This doesn't actually work? See `('a' or 'b') in 'b' `', it evaluates to 'a' in 'b' always.

Comment: WARNING - this doesn't work like it's implied to in the answer. If you say `(x or y or z) in l`, `(x or y or z)` evaluates to the first "truthy" value of the three. E.g., `(0 or 1 or 3) == 1` and `([] or "" or 7 or 1) == 7`. This **does not** give you a way to check multiple containment expressions at once.